# Building electron app for web browser

Tags: webpack, electron

I am not familiar with electron but am looking to rebuild an electron app so it can be included in my server side code and served up so it will work in a general web browser. I was wondering if this is possible using webpack or rollup, or if there is something fundamental I am missing, this is an open source electron app that we need embedded and the native dev team said they do not have resources to help, so no worries on licenses and such has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron is a container that runs any kind of web app, it could be react, angular or just simple html and javascript. So it is possible to convert any electron application to a web app. But it may need some tuning, because electron also contains the server side code (obviously). Usage of webpack or rollup may depend on the web application that is running inside the electron.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Before even digging for the server side, how would you emulate the ipc* and window namespaces in a browser ?